# how set editable cells in ng2-smart-table?

Tags: angular, ng2-smart-table

I'm using a ng2-smart-table component, but i cant find an option, which set a cell is editable, like this example (http://akveo.com/blur-admin/#/tables/smart table marek as "EDITABLE CELLS")
Please, help me - can I edit each cell separately in ng2-smart-table
Thanks!

Comment: are you able to create a EDITABLE CELLS using ng2-smart-table.

Answer (score 0):

You can set by setting **editable:True**

```
actions: actions,
     Yourcolumns: {
      YourColumnName: {
        title: 'Name',
        filter:true,
        editable:True,
        type:'html'

     }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using below code.

```
actions: { add: true, edit: true, delete: false, position: 'right' },
columns: {
       columnname: {
                title: 'Column Name',
                type: 'string',
                editable: true
       }
}
```